# Implementing BlogEngine as an application within Umbraco

Tags: iis, umbraco, blogengine.net

I have an installation of Umbraco v4.9.0 within which I am trying to get a working install of BlogEngine.NET v2.6.0.5

This is in IIS8 on a Windows 8 machine.

I have so far been able to set up BlogEngine within a sub folder and the application works just fine until I try to open a page with the `cshtml` extension.

The error i am getting is

> This type of page is not served.
>
> Description: The type of page you have requested is not served because
>   it has been explicitly forbidden.  The extension '.cshtml' may be
>   incorrect.   Please review the URL below and make sure that it is
>   spelled correctly.
>
> Requested URL: /blog/admin/default.cshtml

Both web.configs have entries designed to prevent this error from happening.

**Umbraco**

```
<buildProviders>
<add extension=".cshtml" 
     type="umbraco.MacroEngines.RazorBuildProvider, umbraco.MacroEngines" />
<add extension=".vbhtml" 
     type="umbraco.MacroEngines.RazorBuildProvider, umbraco.MacroEngines" />
<add extension=".razor" 
     type="umbraco.MacroEngines.RazorBuildProvider, umbraco.MacroEngines" />
</buildProviders>
```

**BlogEngine**

```
<buildProviders>
<remove extension=".cshtml" />
<add extension=".cshtml" 
type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.RazorBuildProvider, System.Web.WebPages.Razor"/>
</buildProviders>
```

I have the relevant MVC binaries in the respective bin folders and I've even tried adding request filtering instructions to both web.configs e.g

```
<requestFiltering>
    <fileExtensions>
        <add fileExtension=".cshtml" allowed="true" />
    </fileExtensions>
</requestFiltering>
```

Have I missed something obvious?

Answer (score 0):

Is your IIS site running in Classic or Integrated mode? Try switching to Integrated mode and see if that fixes your issue.

Comment: I'll have a look at that. Cheers!

Comment: Not actually had the chance to do it. Will see if I can tonight and get back to you.